# Duplicate Files Copied in APK - Android

Tags: java, android, apache, gradle, apk

I want to use

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

I've added     `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in android {} tags in build.gradle (App)
and have added  `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'` in my dependencies. 
My app (build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.ggg.app1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.microsoft.cognitive:speakerrecognition:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'

}
```

My project (build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've looked for answers but nothing solves my problem. I am getting an error --

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

and

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
    File2: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5.1\eecbb0b998e77629862a13d957d552b3be58fc4e\httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
```

Please help! :(

Comment: You only need legacy library .Remove `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'` this line. httpcomponents are added 2 times ie why you are getting DuplicateFileException.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below in your `build.gradle` section

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

**USE**

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Then ***Clean-Rebuild-RUN*** .

Comment: I added
`packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }`
and it worked. But i want to understand why. Could you please tell me if you know?

Comment: @UrviG call `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'`

Comment: It runs now correctly, by adding the snippet which is in the first comment.

Comment: @UrviG Overcome from this problem ??